# Travelling to Mexico with an Italian carta di soggiorno illimitata

Tags: mexico, pakistani-citizens, italian-residents, permesso-di-soggiorno

I am a Pakistani citizen with an Italian *carta di soggiorno illimitata* (Polizia di Stato). I would like to travel to Mexico for tourism purposes. I don't have a visa; is it possible to travel without one?

Comment: Good starting point: https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm Put your specific details in and see what you get.

Comment: What is the purpose of your visit?

Comment: Just for tour to see the country 

Comment: Midavalo's Answer is correct. Note too, however, that you must also be able to enter and transit whatever other countries you'll pass through on your way to and from Mexico — and that means both paperwork (as you've asked about here) as well as COVID-related health restrictions, tests, vaccines, and/or quarantines. Each of those countries may have requirements different from those of Mexico.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this page](https://embamex.sre.gob.mx/finlandia/index.php/traveling/visas) (Mexican government Relaciones Exteriores website), if you have permanent residency in the Schengen Area you don't need a visa.  Your passport needs to have more than 6 months of validity, and you'll need an FMM (typically you'd get these on the flight into Mexico, but can be done online and printed out).

> No visa required If you are a citizen in the Schengen Area, UK, USA,
> Canada or Japan or if you have a **permanent residence permit or a valid
> visa for any of those countries**, you DO NOT REQUIRE A VISA to visit
> Mexico under the following conditions:
>
> The purpose of your visit is tourism, studies or business. The
> duration of your stay does not exceed 180 days. You will not receive
> any remuneration at all from Mexico. However, it is necessary to have:
>
> 1. A valid passport with more than 6 months of validity (Mexican authorities require a passport to be valid for the duration of the
>    stay in Mexico, but the transit countries and airline companies may
>    have other requirements).
> 2. A properly completed Multiple Migratory Form (FMM). The FMM can be obtained from the airline or at the port of entry, but to expedite
>    your registration at the border, you can now fill out and print it in
>    advance in this link.
>
> Remember to keep the FMM in a safe place during your trip! You will be
> asked for it at your departure from Mexico.

To gain entry with a Visa Exemption based on your residency status, the same page says:

> #### Visa exemptions
>
> Permanent residents must prove the permanent resident status to the immigration officer in Mexico at the port of
> entry

But as Hilmar points out in a comment, it wouldn't hurt to confirm for yourself specifically by entering your own details on the IATA Website [Passport/Visa check page](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm).

Comment: Hello I would like some help I am from Pakistan and I have Italian premente residence card ( carta di soggiorno illimitata ) and I when i travel to Mexico on the 25th October to Cancun airport they deported me on the same day with plane that I came from Italy and when I ask them the reason they didn’t say anything and I have returns tickets with my hotel reservation everything completed so when I ask the consult of Milan they told me that they have no idea why they deported me so would someone explain me what can I do please????